# npm install mongpdb: How do I install mongodb in location: c:\mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gruntjs, npm

I've been following this tutorial : http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2014/restful-web-app-node-express-mongodb/, and I don't understand what I need to do in order to get my app to use it.  I've successfully installed everything with node.js up until to where the directions at
     part4: mongodb
     mongo
this call doesn't start the mongodb like it should.  I've installed mongodb and saved in     C:\mongo    like the directions suggest but I can't access the mongo console.  My guess is that I don't have it in the right path because when I try:

```
C:\mongo\   
mongod --dbpath c:\node\nodetest2\data

c:\mongo\
use nodetest3
```

it throws:
     "use is not recognized as an internal command...etc"
That leads me to believe that it's not installed correctly after I do:

```
  npm install mongodb
```

Another troubleshooting idea I have is trying to correct the variable path, maybe?  It's probably a much more simple issue about it's file placement/installation directory.  I'm at a total loss at this point.

I want to reiterate that I've tried the directions in the other similar questions that have already been asked, but it doesn't seem to work.  I think I need more detailed questions, where my experience level isn't assumed (I know that  this is a beginner tut, and its database section is just little a above my expertise at this point.

Comment: Try `mongoose` npm module. It is often used and easy. http://mongoosejs.com/index.html

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=241&v=hX5louVryOQ this may help

Comment: I came across mongoose earlier.  Is it right to install in      c:\node    ?

Comment: @litechip That tutorial seems perfect, thanks a lot!  It seems like a different installation process than I had done earlier today so it should work.  Thanks again!

Comment: It keeps installing without the .exe, I tried installing it with ui and through cmd, and it just seems to be creating the directory without any of the essesntial guts

Comment: forget that last comment, I found the bin in a completely different location.  My mistake.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not sure if you've resolved your issue, but it looks like you haven't actually installed a MongoDB server yet. For instructions, see [Install MongoDB on Windows](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/) in the manual. In general, you're probably better referencing the official documentation which is actively updated and versioned (i.e. you can change between the documentation for the latest version of MongoDB or older versions, which may differ in features or behaviour).

Comment: @Stennie Thanks for noticing that; I'm going to download that right now and report back right after

Comment: Actually, If mongod is the server, than that's already installed.  I'm able to store the values in the db but I'm just having trouble connecting it to my application now.